# Multiple Input Attachments PHP

Tags: php, forms, attachment

I'm trying to process a form that requires multiple file inputs (in different parts of the form), which may have multiple attachment for each one.  I have set each input like this w/ the same name(attach), as I understand it, the $_FILES['attach'] will get all files, correct?

```
 <input type="file" class="file" name="attach[]" title="" dropzone="copy" multiple="multiple" required></input>
```

I've cobbled this php together from a number of sources, could you please review this. It doesn't send, so obviously I've made some errors somewhere.

```
(other variables not shown, but sanitized as well)
$attachments = $_FILES['attach'];
// email body
$mes_body = "<html><head></head><body>";
// $mes_body .= "<img src='http://www.domain.com/marketing/image.png' alt='Image' /><br /><br />"; (optional header image)
// Sanitize unknown input data
function sanitize(text) {
  $san =  filter_var(text, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  return $san;
}
$mes_body .= "<br /><br />";  
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { //define & insert unknown inputs into message body
  if ($key != 'From' && $key != 'Subject' && $key != 'Filecheck') {
    $mes_body .= sanitize($key) . ': ' . sanitize($value) . '<br />';
  }
}
$mes_body .= "</body></html>";
// multipart email
$boundary = md5("text_for_hash");
if ($filecheck == 1) { // multipart email w/ attachment(s) & $filecheck=1 means files present
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From: " . $from_email . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from_email . "" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n";
    // message text
    $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
    $body .= $mes_body;
    $body .= "boundary = $boundary\r\n";
    // attachment(s)
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
      if ($attachment['size']) {
        $body .= "\r\n" . $boundary;
        $body .= "Content-Type: " . $attachment['type'] . "; name=\"". $attachment['filename'] . "\"\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
        $body .= $attachment['content'];
      }  
    }
    $body .= "boundary = $boundary\r\n";
    $message_body = $mes_body;
}
else { // plain text email
  $headers = "From: " . $from_email . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $from_email . "\r\n" . "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
  $message_body = $mes_body;
}
$send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);
```

UPDATE:
Focusing on the attachment part. I'm using FormData & a typical key/value console output right before attaching to FormData might look like this:

[image]

Files1 & Files2 are keys & I need to place these in the email as well. Ex:
Files1: (attach all files associated w/ Files1)
Files2: (attached all files associated w/ Files2)
Note: I won't know the names of the keys ahead of time, as they are user-defined.

Someone suggested this for the attachment part, as it's already FormData:

```
// attachment(s)
foreach ($_FILES as $attachment) {
      $name = $attachment["tmp_name"];
      if ($attachment["size"]) {
        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: " . $attachment["type"] . "; name=\"" . $name . "\"; Content-Disposition: attachment" . "\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
        echo $attachment . "<br />";
      }  
    }
```

Right now the form is submitting silently & I don't see anything is error_log on the server.  What am I doing wrong - code correction would be appreciated.

Comment: @u_mulder Would you mind helping me with this?, as you were helpful w/ another part of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_FILES` is a 2-dimensional array. The first index is the field name to which the file was uploaded, the second index is the information about the file. Instead of the following loop:

```
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
  if ($attachment['size']) {
    $body .= "\r\n" . $boundary;
    $body .= "Content-Type: " . $attachment['type'] . "; name=\"". $attachment['filename'] . "\"\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= $attachment['content'];
  }  
}
```

(`$attachments` was just your first attachment, not all of them), you might want to try:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $attachment) {
  if ($attachment['size']) {
    $body .= "\r\n" . $boundary;
    $body .= "Content-Type: " . $attachment['type'] . "; name=\"". $attachment['filename'] . "\"\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= base64_encode(file_get_contents($attachment['tmp_name']));
  }  
}
```

This will walk through *all* of your attachments, read in the file contents and base64 encode them before appending them to your email message.

Comment: Yeah, ok I see how that would get the files.  Still have problem w/ keys, but I think I'm on the right track.